# Adsense ads don't show up, only "Ads by Google" and a textbox

Tags: adsense

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post this question. Feel free to close this thread if needed. But here's my question:

The page where the ad is located is http://engineercreativity.com/adsense.html

I copy/pasted the ad code and placed it in a simple page (because it wasn't working on my actual website).

The ad code is for an adsense "Ad for Content". It's supposed to be something like:

```
Ads by Google    Ad1    Ad2   Ad3  ....
```

But it shows:

```
Ads by Google   textbox  button
```

Is there a way to fix this. I'm sure it's not related to the code, but rather to the Google Ads settings. Are any of you familiar with Google Adsense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working as intended. It doesn't have any ads to show because of the lack of actual content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You inserted the ad correctly. But did you mean to set the ad's height to 15?

And as [Matt H answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408378/adsense-ads-dont-show-up-only-ads-by-google-and-a-textbox/3408398#3408398), you'll have to wait for Google to crawl your site before it serves relevant advertisements.

[Google AdSense: Confirm the ad shows on your site](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25731&topic=25733&answer=167436)

Comment: Got it. So if I put it on a page with content, it'll actually work? And I didn't intend to make it 15. That's the way I got the code, copy/paste...Weird...